# Update content on the fly

Tags: content

I  am adding function to replace content on the fly for every `width="*"` with width="730px"
and every `height="*"`with height="846"

```
function replace_content_on_the_fly($text){
    $replace = array(
        // 'words to find' => 'replace with this'
        'width="*"' => 'width="730px"',
        'height="*"' => 'height="486px"'

    );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_content_on_the_fly');
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'replace_content_on_the_fly');
```

However,it doesn't seem to work, anyone know to fix it?

Comment: Fix the formatting of the code please.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are trying to replace width="" where "" means empty, you do not need to use "*" when using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), as [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) do not support regular expression. In that case you function will be as :

```
function replace_content_on_the_fly($text){
    $replace = array(
        // 'words to find' => 'replace with this'
        'width=""' => 'width="730px"',
        'height=""' => 'height="486px"'

    );
    $text = str_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
    return $text;
}
```

If you want to replace all width height what so ever is between "", you need to use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
function replace_content_on_the_fly($text){
      $newWidth = 730;
          $newHeight = 486;        

$text = preg_replace(
   array('/width="\d+"/i', '/height="\d+"/i'),
   array(sprintf('width="%d"', $newWidth), sprintf('height="%d"', $newHeight)),
   $text);

        return $text;
    }
```

Comment: the width="*" or height="*" suppose not empty,suppose to have "star" sign for every number (width="450px",width="320px",etc),but when I typed it here, the star sign in middle missing

Comment: @user31445 if width and height are not empty use preg_replace instead of str_replace.

Comment: Is this the right one?



`function replace_content_on_the_fly($text){
    $replace = array(
        // 'words to find' => 'replace with this'
        'width="*"' => 'width="730px"',
        'height="*"' => 'height="486px"'

    );
    $text = preg_replace(array_keys($replace), $replace, $text);
    return $text;
} `

Comment: @user31445 Check i have edited my answer with updated preg_replace function..

Comment: @user31445 You can accept the answer if helpfull..